# Exception has occurred: CLR/System.AggregateException

Tags: c#, .net, flutter, asp.net-core

i try to debug the code i got from tutorial but i got this error in build. im using .Net 6

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll: 'Some services are not able to be constructed'
 Inner exceptions found, see $exception in variables window for more details.
 Innermost exception     System.InvalidOperationException : Unable to activate type 'fixit.Data.DataContext'. The following constructors are ambiguous:
Void .ctor(Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration)
Void .ctor(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[fixit.Data.DataContext])
```

this is my program.cs. i changed this a lot because its hard to rewrite from startup.cs .net 5 witout getting an error

```
using fixit.Data;
using fixit.Models;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);



// Add services to the container

builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(opt => opt.UseMySql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebApiDatabase"), 
ServerVersion.AutoDetect(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebApiDatabase"))));
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
builder.Services.AddCors(option =>
            {
                option.AddPolicy("allowedOrigin",
                    builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader()
                    );
            });
builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepository<Service>, ServiceRepository>();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}

app.UseCors(builder => builder
       .AllowAnyHeader()
       .AllowAnyMethod()
       .AllowAnyOrigin()
    );
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
});

app.Run();
```

i getting an error exception in line  *var app = builder.Build();* . this is my datacontext.cs because its seems like the error come from here.

```
using fixit.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace fixit.Data

{
    
    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        protected readonly IConfiguration Configuration;

    public DataContext(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        // connect to mysql with connection string from app settings
        var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebApiDatabase");
        options.UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString));
    }
        public DataContext() { }
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options) { }

            public DbSet<Service> Service { get; set; }
        
        }
}
```

how to solve this? i try to integrate flutter with web-api and im using api controller,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this issue is using `DataContext` constructors twice, then we get the error message `The following constructors are ambiguous`.

#### Solution

Change your code like below, and the issue will be fixed.

```
using fixit.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Web.Services.Description;

namespace fixit.Data
{
    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        protected readonly IConfiguration Configuration;

        public DataContext() { }
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options, IConfiguration configuration) : base(options) {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        {
            // connect to mysql with connection string from app settings
            var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebApiDatabase");
            options.UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString));
        }
        public DbSet<Service> Service { get; set; }

    }
}
```